# How to read values (possibly NULL) from database into std::vector via Poco::Data?

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, poco-libraries

I want to read many rows (values may be NULL) from a SQL-Server database into an `std::vector`. Reading a single value both NULL and non-NULL works. But I have problems reading multiple values.

Following the [POCO Data User Guide](https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-DataUserManual.html#4), I came up with the following code:

Boilerplate code before:

```cpp
Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
Poco::Data::Session session("ODBC", makeConnectionString());
Poco::Data::Statement select(session);
```

Code **ok**, reading a single value:

```cpp
// note initialization here: otherwise ODBCHandleException will be thrown on non-NULL-value
Poco::Nullable<std::string> n = std::string("");

select << "SELECT col_name FROM table_name WHERE id=6;", into(n);
select.execute();
```

Code **not ok**, reading multiple values, throws `Poco::Data::ODBC::HandleException`:

```
// how to initialize here?
std::vector<Poco::Nullable<std::string>> ns;

select << "SELECT col_name FROM table_name;", into(ns);
select.execute(); // <- error thrown here
```

Any suggestion how I can fix my code?

Comment: I am not good at c++ and Poco libraries but what about using ```IsNull``` in select statement  ```select IsNull(col_Name , '')```

Comment: Your code looks ok. I would try to catch the exception and print what is the error using the `displayText()` function of the exception object. Double check things like column name and table name, and whether the column data type is text.

Comment: try with `std::list` instead of `std::vector`

Comment: Thank you all for your effort. @Yogesh you gave me the hint for the solution I came up with in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many approaches were tried out. In the end I replaced the `std::vector` by `Poco::Data::RecordSet`. Now I can iterate over its `Poco::Data::Row`s, which in turn gives me the column values typed as `Poco::Dynamic::Var`. Here `Poco::Dynamic::Var::isEmpty()` lets me check if the database entry is NULL.

See the **simplified** code for clarification:

```cpp
Poco::Data::ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
Poco::Data::Session session("ODBC", makeConnectionString());

Poco::Data::Statement select(session);
select << "SELECT col_name FROM table_name";
select.execute();

Poco::Data::RecordSet rows(select);        // use Recordset here instead of vector...

std::vector<std::string> beans;            // ...and convert it to vector...

auto convert = [&](Poco::Data::Row row)    // ...with this lambda function.
{
    const Poco::Dynamic::Var var = row["col_name"];

    if (var.isEmpty())                     // convert NULL values to empty string
        return std::string("");

    return var.convert<std::string>();
};

std::transform(rows.begin(), rows.end(), std::back_inserter(beans), convert);

for (const auto& b : beans)
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

The nice thing is, that it scales to a **more sophisticated** version (only read, if you're deeply interested):

```cpp
class GenericTableManager
{
public:
    GenericTableManager(Poco::Data::Session& session, const std::string& tableName);

    template <class T_Bean>
    std::vector<T_Bean> selectAll(std::function<T_Bean(Poco::Data::Row)> convert) const
    {
        Poco::Data::Statement select(m_session);
        select << "SELECT * FROM " << m_tableName;
        select.execute();

        Poco::Data::RecordSet rows(select);

        std::vector<T_Bean> beans;
        std::transform(rows.begin(), rows.end(), std::back_inserter(beans), convert);
        return beans;
    }

    template <class T_Bean>
    size_t insert(
        const T_Bean& bean,
        std::function<Poco::Data::Row(const T_Bean&)> convert) const
    {
        const Poco::Data::Row row = convert(bean);

        Poco::Data::Statement stmt(m_session);
        stmt << "INSERT INTO " << m_tableName
            << " (" << StringUtil::join(*row.names()) << ") "
            << "VALUES (" << placeholders(row.fieldCount()) << ")";

        for (const auto& value : row.values())
            stmt.addBind(Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(value));

        return stmt.execute();
    }
    
private:
    Poco::Data::Session& m_session;
    const std::string m_tableName;

    static std::string placeholders(const size_t n);
};


// on caller side:

// once you have your ORM converters set up...
auto convertOOtoR = [](const MyBean& bean) -> Poco::Data::Row {
    Poco::Data::Row row;
    row.append("myattr1", bean.myattr1);
    row.append("myattr2", bean.myattr2);
    return row;
};

auto convertRtoOO = [](Poco::Data::Row row) -> MyBean{
    MyBean bean;
    Poco::Dynamic::Var var = row["myattr1"];
    bean.myattr1 = var.isEmpty() ? "" : var.convert<std::string>();
    // ...
    return bean;
};

// ...the SQL part boils down to a oneliner
GenericTableManager tm(session, "mytablename");
tm.insert<MyBean>(createMyBean(), convertOOtoR);
std::vector<MyBean> beans = tm.selectAll<MyBean>(convertRtoOO);
```

Comment: If you use RecordSet you'll have overhead. Why? Because you will copy data from db to RecordSet and them from. If you use TypeHandler and bindings you will directly copy data and deserialize data from db to your container. I have the same question as topicstarter and i have no idea how to do it without RecordSet.